# Error when installing channel: "Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Unknown consortium name: SampleConsortium"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

When I try to install a channel it gives me the following error:

```
Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Unknown consortium name: SampleConsortium
```

On the orderer I get the following WARN:

```
Rejecting broadcast of config message from 172.18.0.3:57490 because of error:Unknown consortium name: SampleConsortium
```

I am not referencing sample consortium In any way, I cant find it In any of the generated channel artifacts and on the logs of, peer, orderer, and cli does not appear any other feedback.

I am using version 1.4

I will be happy to share more info.

EDIT1:

I see something weird when using the command **create** on the cli I get the following feedback:

```
[common.tools.configtxgen.localconfig] Load -> INFO 002 Loaded configuration: /etc/hyperledger/fabric/configtx.yaml
```

And when seeing that config Is a default template of the configtx file. Why is it doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The consortium is defined in the file called `configtx.yaml` (specifically in the `Profile` section) , this is the file is used to create orderer genesis block and is embedded in docker-compose yaml file in orderer config section.

When you do `docker-compose up` this block is hardcoded into the orderer along with a system channel called `testchainid`. To verify the same, look up the docker logs by `docker logs -f <orderer.example.com or whatever the url is>`.

Looks like you have misconfigured configtx file, refer [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go/blob/master/test/fixtures/config/config_test.yaml) file for better reference.

Specifically, You probably wrote something like

```
Profiles:
    mychannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
           ...
```

And missed defining the `SampleConsortium` in the genesis profile like

```
Profile:
    TwoOrgGenesis:
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - <<: *org1
                      Policies:
                          ....
```

After making required modifications in the configtx file, recreate the artifacts including genesis.block, channel.tx, anchors.tx before restarting the network.