# during channel creation Error: got unexpected status: BAD_REQUEST -- Consortium config value missing

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am building hyperledger fabric network with 4 ordering service. I have 4 virtual machines and 4 orderer containers. I separated the orderers and I wrote the configtx.yaml file. The configtx.yaml file is as follows. I saw the almost same the stackoverflow question and I applied it but still I get the same error. Maybe this question's answer will be more detail for who will have the same problem.

[same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54626281/error-when-installing-channel-error-got-unexpected-status-bad-request-unk)

configtx.yaml

```
Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg1
        Name: OrdererOrg1
        ID: OrdererMSP1
        MSPDir: ../../setup1/vm1/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP1.member', 'OrdererMSP1.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP1.admin','OrdererMSP1.member','OrdererMSP1.peer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP1.admin')"

    - &OrdererOrg2
        Name: OrdererOrg2
        ID: OrdererMSP2
        MSPDir: ../../setup1/vm2/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP2.member', 'OrdererMSP2.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP2.admin','OrdererMSP2.member','OrdererMSP2.peer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP2.admin')"
    - &OrdererOrg3
        Name: OrdererOrg3
        ID: OrdererMSP3
        MSPDir: ../../setup1/vm3/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP3.member', 'OrdererMSP3.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP3.admin','OrdererMSP3.member','OrdererMSP3.peer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP3.admin')"
    - &OrdererOrg4
        Name: OrdererOrg4
        ID: OrdererMSP4
        MSPDir: ../../setup1/vm4/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP4.member', 'OrdererMSP4.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP4.admin','OrdererMSP4.member','OrdererMSP4.peer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('OrdererMSP4.admin')"

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP

        MSPDir: ../../setup1/vm1/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin', 'Org1MSP.peer', 'Org1MSP.client')"
            Writers:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin','Org1MSP.member','Org1MSP.peer')"
            Admins:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.admin')"
            Endorsement:
                Type: Signature
                Rule: "OR('Org1MSP.peer')"

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051
            # - Host: peer2.org1.example.com
            #   Port: 9051
            # - Host: peer3.org1.example.com
            #   Port: 10051
            # - Host: peer4.org1.example.com
            #   Port: 13051

Capabilities:
    Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
        V2_0: true

    Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
        V2_0: true

    Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
        V2_0: true

Application: &ApplicationDefaults
    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        LifecycleEndorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
        Endorsement:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ApplicationCapabilities

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
    # can be solo | kafka | etcdraft if solo no consenters
    OrdererType: etcdraft 
    EtcdRaft:
        Consenters:
        - Host: orderer.example.com
          Port: 7050
          ClientTLSCert: ../../setup1/vm1/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../../setup1/vm1/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer2.example.com
          Port: 8050
          ClientTLSCert: ../../setup1/vm2/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../../setup1/vm2/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer2.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer5.example.com
          Port: 9050
          ClientTLSCert: ../../setup1/vm3/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../../setup1/vm3/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer5.example.com/tls/server.crt
        - Host: orderer4.example.com
          Port: 10050
          ClientTLSCert: ../../setup1/vm4/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt
          ServerTLSCert: ../../setup1/vm4/crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer4.example.com/tls/server.crt

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050
        - orderer2.example.com:8050
        - orderer5.example.com:9050
        - orderer4.example.com:10050

    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10         # max block can hold messages
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB     
        PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Organizations:
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
        BlockValidation:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"

Channel: &ChannelDefaults
    Policies:
        Readers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Readers"
        Writers:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "ANY Writers"
        Admins:
            Type: ImplicitMeta
            Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"

    Capabilities:
        <<: *ChannelCapabilities

Profiles:
    OrdererGenesis:
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
            - *OrdererOrg1
            - *OrdererOrg2
            - *OrdererOrg3
            - *OrdererOrg4
            Capabilities:
                <<: *OrdererCapabilities
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                - *Org1
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Readers"
            Writers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
            Admins:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
            BlockValidation:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"

           
    BasicChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        <<: *ChannelDefaults
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
            Capabilities:
                <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
        Policies:
            Readers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Readers"
            Writers:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "ANY Writers"
            Admins:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
            LifecycleEndorsement:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
            Endorsement:
                Type: ImplicitMeta
                Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
```